# Assigning Variable Types to numbers java

Tags: java, variables, boolean, superclass

I'm trying to figure out how to assign multiple variables to int type but I'm not sure how to assign it to them. Also, I'm having difficulty understanding how you can use a boolean with this restriction. I was thinking about putting them in an array but I'm not sure if there is an easier approach to the problem. Any help is much appreciated!

Instructions for Attraction.java

Write a Java program Attraction.java that has the following characteristics.

extends Place 
New attributes: type (int) price (double) 
New Methods: public Attraction(String name, String desc, double latitude, double longitude, double price, int type) where for ***type*** values:

0 is an amusement park
1 is an aquarium
2 is a zoo
public double getPrice() -- returns current price

public int getType() -- returns type

public boolean hasAnimals() -- returns true if type contains "zoo" or "aquarium"

Comment: `assign multiple variables to int type` I have no idea what you mean by this.

Comment: You cannot assign *multiple values to int type*, and your assignment does not ask you to do so. There is no *restriction* that would prevent you from using a boolean as instructed in the assignment, either. If you're unclear about everything in your assignment, you should ask your instructor or teaching assistant for help. This isn't a tutorial or homework completion site.

Comment: @KenWhite  I am confused as to how you would assign the variables of the type category. I would not ask if I knew the answer to my question and its out of genuine uncertainty that I am posting this on this site. To make my question clearer, I am wondering how to assign, for instance: 0 to "aquarium" within the getType method.

Comment: It's simple. A type is **one** of either *amusement park*, *aquarium* or *zoo*. It can't be all three. (It's `type`, not `list of types` or `array of types`, right?)

Comment: @John3136 To make my question clearer, I am wondering how to assign, for instance: 0 to "aquarium" within the getType method along with 1 and 2.

Comment: You haven't learned about `if` and `else` yet? You really need to go back and ask your instructor for help. The assignment you were given is pretty basic, and the explanation of the task is pretty clear.

Comment: @KenWhite exactly! i just don't know how I could write that and declare those variables if that makes sense?

Comment: See the comment I just posted, and then go ask your instructor for help. This is basic information, and we're not a tutorial or homework site, as I said previously. If you haven't learned the basics in class so far, your instructor hasn't done their job properly.

Comment: @KenWhite im not sure if this is correct but i have  public int getType(){
  if (type == 0) {
   System.out.println("amusement park");
  if (type == 1){
    System.out.println("aquarium");
   
  if (type == 2) { 
   System.out.println("zoo");
  }
  }
  }
 return type;
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `hasAnimals` method needs to return a `boolean` value i.e. `true` or `false` based on the value of the `type` variable.

You're .. kind of on the right track, but you're not honoring the requirements of the method. It shouldn't print anything, and it shouldn't return `type` because `type` is an `int` and not the `boolean` that is required.

```
public boolean hasAnimals() {
    if(type == 1) {
        return true; // aquarium has animals
    } else if (type == 2) {
        return true; // zoo has animals
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Think carefully about what a method is called, and what it should do. This method is just a way to answer a yes/no question.

Comment: Thank you! ive beenm staring at this for hours trying to figure it out. I really needed to figure out the first portion of assigning the numbers to variables and now it makes so much sense!

Comment: No problem, sometimes an example can clarify things.